# How to add dates dynamically on x-axis on line graph in android

Tags: java, android, spring

```
GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
GridLabelRenderer gridLabel = graph.getGridLabelRenderer();
gridLabel.setHorizontalAxisTitle("Dates");
gridLabel.setVerticalAxisTitle("Status");

for (int i = 10; i >= 1; i--) {
    Calendar pastDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    pastDate.add(Calendar.DATE, -i);
    String beforedate = pastDate.get(Calendar.DATE) + "/" +(pastDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" + pastDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    Log.i("paste date is:", beforedate);
}
```

Comment: I don't think android has `GraphView` class. Please mention what lib you are using ?

Comment: I used GraphView-4.2.1.jar library

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
gridLabel.setHorizontalLabels(new String[]{"1/1/1970", "1/2/1970", "1/3/1970"});
```

Comment: I am using   GridLabelRenderer gridLabel = graph.getGridLabelRenderer();           gridLabel.setHorizontalLabels(new String[]{"1/1/1970", "1/2/1970", "1/3/1970"});     I got the error: The method setHorizontalLabels(String[]) is undefined for the type GridLabelRendere